# How do I install Viber without a phone?

Tags: viber

I do not have a smartphone or my smartphone does not support Viber, how can I install and use it on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This installation will still require a phone capable of receiving SMS.

```
sudo snap install --devmode --beta anbox
sudo snap install viber-unofficial
sudo apt install android-tools-adb
```

You will need download a copy of the x86_64 Viber APK, once you have done that start Anbox and run

```
adb install <PATH TO VIBER APK>
```

Now open the desktop version of Viber (the one you installed via Snap), it will ask you if you have Viber installed on your phone, select 'yes' and enter a phone number.
You should now see a QR code, below it there should be a link that says 'My camera is not working. What can I do?', click on it, it will ask you if you want to copy the link, click 'copy'.
Now go to Anbox, click on Viber, go through the regular setup process, entering a real phone number that can recieve text messages. Once the setup process is complete, create a contact, and send them the previously copied link and click on it. Viber desktop should now ask you if you want to sync, click yes on both the desktop and mobile version of Viber.

Now that the setup process is complete you can uninstall Anbox and adb:

```
sudo snap remove anbox
sudo apt purge android-tools-adb
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install Viber for any gadget or PC without a real phone number using a disposable virtual number for registration. https://hottelecom.biz/virtual-number-for-viber.html The format of this number does not differ in appearance from a mobile number.